# Should users be asked whether they're good in English before making a post?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

There are many posts with bad formatting and English. They're just mixed in with everything else; it's just unorganised.

So, should we ask users if their post has good English and punctuation?

> Yes

> May have some problems

I think it'll help perform triage in review. Look, this is totally not shaming because people's bad English is hilariously displayed in their post anyway (including mine sometimes). However, a `bad english` tag might be arguable for being shaming. I don't think so, but I think people may have different opinions. So, let's leave the tag thing for another day. I just request for asking the user of their English and prioritising the ones with bad English in review queues. Maybe even a new review queue, "Potentially bad English"?

Comment: *"weather"*, *"a bad english"*, *"I just request for"* -  So let me ask you, would you have picked good or bad English from the options when you were writing this post?

Comment: It wouldn't be practical in the least. If someone's having issues with English being a second language - then feel free to try and help them out. Otherwise it's not something that can be done via review queues etc...

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve and how does this solve it?

Comment: @Nick The "weather" thing was my spelling check misbehaving. I was missing the word "tag" after `bad english`, not actually a grammatical error, just a missed word. "I just request for" seems completely okay to me.

Comment: And therein lies the problem in asking users to rate their own English. "My spell checker misbehaved", "I forgot a word", "It looks right to me", if every user who makes mistakes in English says these things and says "Yes, my English is perfect", then this feature would ultimately be worthless.

Comment: @Nick Well, people know they're bad in English. We get people saying "soory for my bad english" as their first sentence. Everybody misses a comma but some people are extremely bad and they know it. Nothing capitalised, some full-stops, no regard for plurality of the verb and the list goes on.

Comment: `Bad english` rarely is the real problem for any questions posted here, but lack of understanding how the site is intended to work is.

Comment: The problem not only is with not native speakers but also devices like Handys(mobiles) which seem to have their own idea or smal buttons . So simply take the  time and correct them

Comment: @nbk It's unfortunate that you chronically don't follow that very advice you give. (Including in that very comment.)

Comment: @Shambhav I'll be a bit of a d*ck here and say anyone that has the self reflection to see they have a bad English, yet still post without triple checking everything (which would mean it won't be that bad "bad English", right?)..... Are a bit insulting to the site. Basically "I know my English isn't good, but I won't try and fix it. Kthx'".....

Comment: As per [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/241919), the site only requires English, that's all. No matter how bad it is, it's okay as long as it's still comprehensible. No need to discriminate/prioritize the bad one: "*As long as the question is in salvageable English and makes some modicum of sense, it should be edited and improved **like any other post.***"

Comment: @philipxy I correct hundreds of posts Every year , but they get often closed and deleted and the problem isn't the language it is the content that is bad.

Comment: @nbk What I meant was that your own comments & posts are full of easily avoided errors.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of [Muphry's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law).

Comment: @philipxy as I wrote on my comment typos come easily and so correct them if you find them

Comment: @PM2Ring I knew that would happen and included the all-catch phrase "including mine sometimes".

Comment: I cannot edit as my rep is too low but a feature request for users to define their level of competence in English when there is a misspelled word in the title is ironic. 1. **weather** (noun: meteorological) 2. **whether** (conjunction)

Comment: P.S the grammar is otherwise perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

> There are many posts with bad formatting and English. They're just mixed in with everything else; it's just unorganised.

I don't think organizing posts by how well they're written is feasible and wouldn't be all that useful even if it were.

First, as was pointed out in the comments, people aren't necessarily going to be good judges as to whether or not their post has a lot of grammar issues. We regularly see people with excellent English apologize for their bad English and I've seen people suggest edits where the edit in grammatical errors.

Secondly, *other* people aren't always the best judges of how much help a post needs. I've seen suggested edits where the person changed one character, added a bunch of nonsense to get past the character limit for edits, and insist in the edit summary that it was the only thing wrong with the post only to find several other issues they could have fixed.

Third, a post with commonplace grammar mistakes isn't necessarily more urgent than a post with different problems. A post that left all the apostrophes out of the contractions (i.e. "isn't") isn't a bigger problem than a post where a formatting problem is hiding the fact that half of the code isn't showing up. The first is still understandable and answerable while the latter would attract down (and possibly close) votes.

I'm also not sure folks will willingly tick a box that will cause their post to get more scrutiny in review queues.

Comment: Could also see this sort of grouping being viewed by those targeted as a being discriminatory or insulting. There can definitely be some negative ramifications

Comment: In fact just being asked in the UI if your english skills suck  would be offensive

Comment: @charlietfl The person's clearly bad English would be shown in the post anyway. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam What doesn't matter? Offending someone by questioning their personal skills? Or insulting them by tagging their post as illiterate? While it might not bother you I don't know how you can speak for the legions of others. Some might be dyslexic, or have other learning disabilities yet be great coders. You still never bothered to answer what the specific problem is that any of this would solve

Comment: @charlietfl Nobody is saying to make a pop up saying "Are you good in English, your last post was shit. The plan was to just ask the user politely if they're good at it or not. Most posts start with "soory for my bad english"(intentional typo). If we start taking offence for every slight bit of hint, society will never progress. Imagine it's offensive to argue to someone else in a serious tone.Those two things are not so far apart. You only start taking offence at these things once you learn English,those guys wont know anything.Im saying from experience,English is full of so called "offence".